# Make a prefix query on whole filed in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

Hi I am having a field called text_field in which i have two document
1.lubricant
2.air lube

I have used Edge-N gram analyzer with term query but in result when i serch with lub

Terms query over filed analyzed with edge n-gram analyzer

```
{
  "terms" : {
    "text_field" : [ "lub" ]
  }
}
```

prefix query over filed analyzed with keyword tokenizer:

```
{
  "prefix" : {
    "text_field" : {
      "prefix" : "lub"
    }
  }
}
```

In both these queries m getting two results in result set 
"lubricant",
"air lube"

I don't want air lube to be in result as it starts with word air,is there any way to make a search prefix query on whole field,looks like here it's checking terms,is there any way to sort this out.

Comment: you need to change the mapping or need to add a extra field `.raw` without analyzation. then search on it with prefix. Hope it helps

Comment: Hi sunkuet ,thanks for reply.
without analyzation you mean to  say "simple string field with not_analyzed right"? what about .raw I didn't get it

Comment: Yes, You got me. About raw fields : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/multi-fields.html

Comment: Check it, know us if any query.